# Convert a .PEM certificate to a PFX certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have three files: ca.pem, cert.pem and key.pem.

How can I convert these files to .PFX using OpenSSL.

I'm running Windows so if there are some other convertor tool besides the OpenSSL, Pls recommend me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: This question has been asked so many times I'm surprised you did not accidentally stumble upon the answer... Perhaps you should search for the answer rather than asking an off-topic and redundant question.